# How to change dynamically from Custom inputView into Default inputView in UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In my app, i need to create custom inputView(keyboard) in `UISearchBar`.

i want to do like following picture.

First pic is default input keyboard(English).

[image]

And Second pic is Custom keyboard.

[image]

I want to do when i tap on default(English) keyboard's  `inputAccessoryView` button, i want to change into my custom input view(following pic). and when i tap again that `inputAccessoryView` button , i want to hide my custom keyboard and change into default keyboard.

i have no idea how to do that.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got answer for my own question.
That's just a trick.

Just use `nil` to `inputView`. :D

Answer (score 2):

UISearchBar API gives you no official access to its text field's `inputView`. But you can get such access by finding the text field, like this:

```
for (UIView* v in searchBar.subviews) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField* tf = (UITextField*)v;
        tf.inputView = //...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: like my question , i also want to change back into default keyboard when i tap inputAccessoryView.How can i do that bro?